# Error message while updating ubuntu 18.04 using terminal

Tags: 18.04, updates

I get the following error messages:

```
N: Ignoring file 'openboard-xenial.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openboard-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Please post the output of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openboard-xenial.list` - as you can see from the error message, this file has errors.

Answer (score 1):

List files like `openboard-xenial.list` have a specific structure. Other than comments or empty lines, every line needs to start with either `deb` (for a repository with binary packages) or `deb-src` (for a repository with source code packages). In your case, line 2 of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openboard-xenial.list` starts with `sudo` for some reason. You need to look into that and correct it.

The other message is a notice that there is a file that is ignored by `apt`, because it doesn't have the proper file name ending. List files need to have a file name ending with `.list`, like your `openboard-xenial.list`. The file `openboard-xenial.list.save.1` has a different ending and is therefore ignored. It may be a backup copy created by some text editor you used to edit your files.

The latter message is only a notice (`N`), compared to an actual error (`E`) like the message about the unknown type `sudo`.